# How do I design a Login page for multiple databases in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

I am working on a company project, in which it contains a data processing system and this system was previously written separately for each bank and have their own project file, and each of the project has their own database that store the user credentials for them to login using their id and password.

Now we need to merge all the projects together so that it only login via a single login page, but i am wondering how am i going to do this because the data, especially the login credentials is stored in different databases. How should I pass data from a database to another database to perform validation?

Comment: Are these Windows or SQL Server authentication logins?

Comment: Nono, login page for my program

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, though. How do the users authenticate against the database? Windows login means you're using some kind of a network account, and users will authenticate against windows. SQL authentication means they will need to provide a username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these are SQL server logins, You will probably have to build a database with an availableDB table listing the available databases.  Let the user choose a database, then try to open that database using the specified credentials, kicking him/her back to the choose-a-database point in the application.

If that doesn't answer your question, we'll need a little more information: architecture, desired interface, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: oright bro, tq trying out ur method now and will get back to you in a short time

Answer (score 0):

Why Dont You Use a drop down on login form with Every bank name listed in Drop Down. After selection of bank, use if and else statements to populate selected bank database.

Comment: coz, we are merging all the previous 4 program into a solely one program, and each of the program has their existing database for login credentials, and my superior doesn't want to merge all the VB.net form together as it is quite difficult for them to do maintenance.

Comment: Suppose you had 4 databases. Create One database with 4 schemas. Every schema contain full database backup accordingly. Call selected bank schema to proceed with login.